# PYODBC ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

Tags: python, pyodbc

This is an overused topic of discussion but the waters are still unclear. I have developed a program that uses pyodbc to connect to a .mdb file, it successfully works when I use the 32-bit version of Python and only if on the consrtuctor string write the following `constr = "DRIVER={{Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}};Dbq={};".format(dbname)` so I naturally thought it was a mismatch between 32bit access and 64bit Python.
However when I tried to make a simple test:

```
    import pyodbc

conn=pyodbc.connect(r'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *accdb)};DBQ=C:\Users\emate\OneDrive\Desktop\pyodbctest\Database2.accdb;')
cursor=conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM Table1')

for row in cursor.fetchall():
    print(row)
```

I ran it and got the same error. The problem is I checked the Office Version and says it is 64bit,python is also 64bit so if it is not a mismatch problem then what is this problem?
I want to run the program on a raspberrypi microcomputer (64bit) and it is tremendously hard to use a 32bit version on it to just run the program.

Comment: Will your Raspberry Pi be running Microsoft Windows? If not, then having it run a Python app that manipulates an Access database is not impossible but it will probably be more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: I had found a way to do it,apparently it can work without actually opening it.I know it is trouble but because it is an app for a pharmacy,the db it produces it is only mdb/accdb. The question at hand is why does the pyodbc keep giving me this message...

Comment: Check the list returned by `pyodbc.drivers()` to see what ODBC drivers are available to your Python app. Also, please clarify: At the moment you're talking about running your app on Windows with 64-bit Office and 64-bit Python. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes my first problem that is bugging me is that I am running the app on 64bit windows 10,on python3.7 64bit and the msaccess is 64bit,and yet I get the error I mentioned above,while if I run it on 32bit python it works perfectly.